# Calculationg perplexity (in natural language processing) manually

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state, monads

I wrote the code below, and now want to rewrite it using a Monad. And with do notation. I tried the do notation below but gets the output. It seems to have something to do with the tuples that I use binding for, which works in the original code:

```
seed::Int
seed = 2

giveList :: [Int]
giveList = [8,9,4,5,2]

generator = mkStdGen seed

giveRandomElement :: [a] -> a
giveRandomElement lst = lst !! rand where
  n = length lst
  (rand, _) = randomR (0,(n-1)) generator

random_response :: R.StdGen -> a -> [a] -> (a, R.StdGen)
random_response g true_answer answers =
  let (val, g') = R.random g
      (val', g'') = R.random g' :: (Bool, R.StdGen)
  in if val then (true_answer, g'') 
     else (giveRandomElement answers , g'')

random_response_monad :: R.StdGen -> a -> [a] -> (a, R.StdGen)
random_response_monad g true_answer answers =  do 
     (val, g') <- R.random g :: (Bool, R.StdGen)
     (val', g'') <- R.random g' :: (Bool, R.StdGen)
     if val then return (true_answer, g'')
     else return (giveRandomElement answers, g'')

OUTPUT:
error:
* Couldn't match expected type `StdGen'
              with actual type `(Bool, StdGen)'
* In the pattern: (val, g')
  In a stmt of a 'do' block: (val, g') <- random g :: (Bool, StdGen)
  In the expression:
    do (val, g') <- random g :: (Bool, StdGen)
       (val', g'') <- random g' :: (Bool, StdGen)
       if val then
           return (true_answer, g'')
       else
           return (giveRandomElement answers, g'')
(val, g') <- R.random g :: (Bool, R.StdGen)
```

I suspect that the type error I get is due to the `<-` rather than the `let`-binding. Is this correct, and where is my conceptual misunderstanding, and how can I fix the code?

Furthermore is it correct that what I am trying to do is rewriting it using a state-monad?

**EDIT: Tried to answer below exercise suggestion**

I have tried the below but get a parser error.

```
random_response_monad :: a -> [a] -> State R.StdGen a
random_response_monad true_answer answers =  do 
    let random' = state $ randomR(0,1)
    val <- random' 
    val' <- random'
    if val then giveRandomElement answers 
    else giveRandomElement answers
```

Note that I changed both branches of if-statement to a call of same function and argument for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you actually want by “rewrite it using a Monad” is indeed rewriting it in the state monad. It's no good using monad syntax if you don't have an actual monad type.

(It so happens that plain tuples can also act as a monad, but better ignore that, it's more confusing than helpful.)

The point of expressing specifically randomized calculations in a state monad is that it avoids the awkward and error-prone carrying around of explicit new versions of the random generator. I.e., you want to replace

```
  let (val, g') = R.random g
      (val', g'') = R.random g'
```

with simply

```
  val <- random'
  val' <- random'
```

To get there, let's first re-order the signature:

```
random_response :: a -> [a] -> (R.StdGen -> (a, R.StdGen))
```

The part in parentheses is basically [`State R.StdGen a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html). In fact you can rewrite it quite easily to have the signature

```
random_response :: a -> [a] -> State R.StdGen a
```

I'll leave that as an exercise, but will address `giveRandomElement` instead, which currently is wrong. Note that `generator` is just a global constant, i.e. `giveRandomElement` will always yield the same element of the list. That's no good.

Instead, this should also have a proper random type, preferrably again the state monad. You can write it thus:

```
giveRandomElement :: [a] -> State R.StdGen a
giveRandomElement lst = do
  let n = length lst
  rand <- state $ randomR (0, n-1)
  return $ lst !! rand
```

Comment: But isn't State R.StdGen a problematic because the `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) } ` and hence it requires that you write (a, s) because that is what you return. R.StdGen is the `s` here I guess!?

Comment: In the link you have posted it mentions `StateT` monad. Is that the same as `State`-monad.

Comment: I am trying to solve the exercise you gave me in the above answer. As part of that I am trying to understand what you are doing in the `giveRandomElement`-modification that you made. Isn't `state` supposed to be `State` and what about the type declaration, what I want to return is a list, not a state. So the above posese conflicts. My output from the change I made just mentioned is: `Couldn't match type `[]' with `State StdGen'
      Expected: State StdGen a
        Actual: [a]`

Comment: [`state`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html#v:state) is the same as what the `State` constructor would be if it was in fact `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a,s) }`. The actual implementation, as the `StateT` monad transformer applied to the `Identity` monad, is equivalent to this, but more flexible since you can also add other monadic effects beyond the state.

Comment: The error message you got seems to be a result of a mistake in my code, see edit.

Comment: I am not completely sure I understand your comment about `state` I shall be reading it several times more. I however do still get an error: `error:
    * Variable not in scope:
        state :: (g0 -> (Int, g0)) -> State StdGen Int
    * Perhaps you meant data constructor `State' (line 201)`

Comment: Wait, are you using your own `State` type or the standard one from the `transformers` package?

Comment: These `import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import qualified System.Random as R`

Comment: So you define `newtype State` yourself?

Comment: Yup like this: `newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) } ` and I haven't made an explicit instance of the State monad yet either, but will be using the one in: http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more if I'm going ot.

Comment: But I see now, that the `state` is mentioned in the link you posted above. I shall try to use that library.

Comment: This worked. I shall continue by looking more into StateT and see if I can rewrite the random_response as you suggested above.

Comment: @Piskator it's not much use to paste multiline Haskell code in comments.

Comment: No you are correct. I was about to  ask if I should open a new post.

Comment: Ok, Now I have edited my post as a way to show you how I have tried to solve it so far. Could you give some more hints?

Comment: You've been mixing `let..in` and `do` syntax. Just remove the `in`.

Comment: Ah... that changed things. There still seems to be something wrong however. When I write `let random' = state $ randomR (0,1)` I get `No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal `0',  * In the expression: 0` . I can't see how mine is different from what you changed `giveRandomElement` into. It also takes a tupple with two integers.

Comment: Well, you can't use `if` with an integer, it needs to take a `Bool`. You can either use `val>0`, or generate a random bool right away.