# Unpacking and printing values from State-Monad in Haskell using get

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

I am trying to get a good grasp of the State-Monad (and Monads in general) but I am struggling with rewriting the below function using the state Monad and the do-notation, which resulted as an exercise for me propose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404325/calculationg-perplexity-in-natural-language-processing-manually/74404591?noredirect=1#comment131448568_74404591)

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import Data.Complex
import qualified System.Random as R
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy

giveRandomElement :: [a] -> State R.StdGen a
giveRandomElement lst = do
  let n = length lst
  rand <- state $ randomR (0, n-1)
  return $ lst !! rand

random_response_monad :: a -> [a] -> State R.StdGen a
random_response_monad true_answer answers = do      
        tal <- state $ randomR (0, 1) :: StateT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a     
        if (tal == 0) then true_answer
        else giveRandomElement answers
```

As is immediately obvious there are some type problems for the `tal`-variable as it occurs in the `if`-clause and the first line of the `do`-expression. As is visible from the code I have tried to force the latter by a specific type in order to make it unambiguous and clearer for myself as well. I have done so by the compiler-suggestion I got when I first tried to force it to be of the `Int`-type. I Am however not able to use that value in an if-statement, and I am unsure of how to convert or unpack the value such that I get it as an `Int`.
So far I have tried to add the folloowing line after `tal <- ...` ,  `resp <- get $ tal` but I get this output.

```
error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: t0
                                    -> StateT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a1
                  with actual type: StateT s0 m0 s0
    * The first argument of ($) takes one value argument,
        but its type `StateT s0 m0 s0' has none
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: resp <- get $ tal
      In the expression:
        do tal <- state $ randomR (0, 1)
           resp <- get $ tal
           if (resp == 0) then
               giveRandomElement answers
           else
               giveRandomElement answers
    * Relevant bindings include tal :: t0
```

Furthermore I am baffled what would be the best way to 'print' the result returned by `giveRandomElement` as the type is based on the type declared for the `State`-monad which as I understand it doesn't use the `deriving Show` also. But this can perhaps be solved by unpacking the value as enquired about above.

**EDIT**

I used the above packages although they are probably not all used in the above code. I am unsure of which is used by the code by I suspect the `qualified System.Random as R`

Comment: I've tried to guess which of the various alternative versions of `State` the above code is using, but I can't reproduce the output (I get another error message). Please update the question to include import statements and which packages are in use.

Comment: Also, please clean up the types. It looks as though the code imports `System.Random` both qualified and unqualified.

Comment: I think that the type of `tal` should not involve the `a` type variable at all. Probably `a` should be replaced by just `Int` in the type expression.

Comment: @MarkSeemann It is using the `import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy` as I have now updated the post with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code line:

```
        tal <- state $ randomR (0, 1) :: StateT StdGen Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a
```

is quite long and might cause a horizontal slider to appear, at least on my platform.

So it is all too easy to overlook that at its very end, the `a` type variable is used, while it should be just `Int`.

Also, the two branches of the `if` construct use different types, making the construct ill-typed. The `then` branch gives a pure `a` value, while the `else` branch gives a monadic value. This is easily fixed by changing to:

```
   if (tal == 0)  then  return true_answer
```

as the (slightly misnamed) `return` library function *wraps* its argument into the monad at hand.

The following code, which tries to keep code lines short enough, seems to work fine:

```
import            Control.Monad.State
import qualified  System.Random          as  R
import qualified  Data.Functor.Identity  as  DFI

giveRandomElement :: [a] -> State R.StdGen a
giveRandomElement lst = do
    let n = length lst
    rand <- state $ R.randomR (0, n-1)
    return $ lst !! rand


type ActionType = StateT R.StdGen DFI.Identity Int

random_response_monad :: a -> [a] -> State R.StdGen a
random_response_monad true_answer answers = do        
        tal <- (state $ R.randomR (0, 1) :: ActionType)
        if (tal == 0)  then  return true_answer
                       else  giveRandomElement answers


main :: IO ()
main = do
    let  g0       =  R.mkStdGen 4243
         action   =  random_response_monad 20 [0..9]
         (k, g1)  =  runState action g0
    putStrLn $ "k is set to: " ++ (show k)
```

Side note: the code can also be made to compile without the complex type annotation, like this:

```
       tal <- state $ R.randomR (0::Int, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough and clear answer.  I wonder though if this code however will not to some degree be deterministic since `g0` is set to 4243 in `main`, or if it can return a purely random response on every call of main.

Comment: I wonder is it possible to use `get` from: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.6.0.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Lazy.html to extract the state, I tried to do that but didn't succeed.

Comment: Yes, as the code stands, using `mkStdGen` with a fixed seed value ensures that the exact same pseudo-random serie will get generated in all successive executions of the program. If you don't want reproducibility, you can use: `g0 <- getStdGen` ; however, in physics “Monte-Carlo” problems, you will typically vary things like temperature or magnetic field from one execution the the next one, and you certainly don't want to blur the effect of that controlled change by moving to some other pseudo-random serie in uncontrolled fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this seems to work:

```
random_response_monad :: a -> [a] -> State R.StdGen a
random_response_monad true_answer answers = do      
  tal <- state $ randomR (0 :: Int, 1)
  if (tal == 0) then return true_answer
  else giveRandomElement answers
```

Two changes:

- Use a type annotation to tell the compiler what you mean by `0` and `1`. Once you've told the compiler which type `0` is, it follows that `1` has the same type. (Keep in mind that in Haskell, numbers are polymorphic. Without more information, Haskell will see a literal such as `0` as potentially any `Num` instance.)
- `return` in front of `true_answer`.

Here's a few samples from GHCi that seems to indicate that it works:

```
ghci> evalState (random_response_monad 42 [0..9]) <$> newStdGen
4
ghci> evalState (random_response_monad 42 [0..9]) <$> newStdGen
1
ghci> evalState (random_response_monad 42 [0..9]) <$> newStdGen
42
```